# Can't negate regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to implement the negation of the following regular expression in JavaScript:

```
^(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+$
```

That expression matches on the following:

- 11111-111-11111
- 22-2222-2222
- 55-55555-55

And not on the following:

- 12-22-3345
- 32-44555-3333

I want it to do the opposite of those scenarios.

I've tried the following regular expressions and they do not work:

```
^(?!(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+)$
^(?!(\d))\1+-(?!(\d))\1+-(?!(\d))\1+$
^(?!(\d)\1+)-(?!(\d)\1+)-(?!(\d)\1+)$
```

I thought I had a solid understanding of what negative lookahead does, but apparently not. What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone point me in the right direction to a solution?

EDIT: Here's a link to mess around with the current regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/jY9mJ6/1

Comment: Your original positive regular expression `^(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+$` that you are trying to negate also matches the following: `11111-21-31111`, `22-5222-6222`, `55-85555-95`, and others. Is that intentional? My impression was that each block of digits should consist of  a single digit.

Comment: That is not intentional! Good catch. They should each consist of a single digit to be matched on. I thought I had figured it out....

Comment: I think what you want for the positive regexp is: `^(\d)\1+-(\d)\2+-(\d)\3+$`. That will require each block to consist of 2 or more of the _same_ digit (but the digits can be different from block to block). Now you just need to negate it using anubhava's solution.

Comment: That won't work either. I'm trying to match that all the blocks are the same digit.

Comment: Oh, if that's the case, that's even easier: `^(\d)\1+-\1+-\1+$`. That assumes blocks 2 and 3 can be 1 or more digits. If you need them to be 2 or more digits: `^(\d)\1+-\1\1+-\1\1+$` or `^(\d)\1+-\1{2,}-\1{2,}$`.

Comment: I wish there was more of a way I could thank you Sam. You helped me immensely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This negative lookahead should work:

```
^(?!(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+$).*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO7kV2/1)

Comment: I forgot to put in that I had tried: ^(?!(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+).*$ at one point. I was so close! Thank you!